# Перевод Wordpress сайта

Tags: wordpress, локализация

Есть сайт на Wordpress на русском языке. а мне его надо перевести на английский и китайский.

Мне нужно, чтобы я мог переключатель языков добавить самостоятельно, с помощью кода куда хочу, в любое место сайта, а не добавлять через админку с помощью виджет панели, как показано во всех уроках.

Comment: Вопрос №1. Чем виджет не угодил? Если виджет не нравится, его можно перезадать через хук. Либо посмотрите, как работает виджет и напиши "пародию"

Comment: Вот тут все написано, думаю поможет.
http://wpruse.ru/plaginy/multiyazychnyj-sajt-wordpress/